# Destroyed Object not Null and can still be Accessed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two unity GameObjects, monster and hunter each has one script.
From monster, I call a function in hunter that destroys the game object. Yet hunter is not nulled. I can see the hunter entity disapear from the screen, its no longer there, but I can still access it and its members.

HunterScript

```
public class HunterScript : MovingEntityScript { // Ultimately inherits from MonoBehaviour

    int hp = 2;

    // Other Stuff

    public void TakeDamage () {
        if (--hp == 0) Destroy(gameobject);
    }

}
```

MonsterScript

```
public class MonsterScript: MovingEntityScript { // Ultimately inherits from MonoBehaviour

    GameObject target; // Is set to the only instance of Hunter on startup

    // Other Stuff

    public void Attack () {
        target.getComponent<HunterScript>().TakeDamage();
        Debug.Log(target==null || target.Equals(null)); // Prints False even when hunter hp == 0;
    }

}
```

If it helps both hunter and monster make heavy use of coroutines including when hunter is meant to be destroyed.

Why does this happen? How can I check if the entity has truly been destroyed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `Destroy` destroys the GameObject only after the current update loop - asynchronously, after your code is run. `Destroy` will remove the GameObject and free some resources. There is `DestroyImmediate`, but it should be avoided under normal circumstances.
2. The variable, `target` in your case, has a reference to the destroyed object and it keeps it, since it is a field. Nothing will set it automagically to null. But this is completely unrelated to `Destroy`.

I think you should trust in Unity destroying the GameObject - but you may try to access some component - which will fail.